# erlang elixir observer ui: what does reds/reductions mean in processes tab?

Tags: erlang, elixir

I was doing the exercise of making a dictionary module, implemented with Agent, that should output random word on `random_word(pid)` function call. After implementation was complete the author asked: "Using the observer (:observer.start), find this process. Double click on it to bring up the process details. Now generate some random words. Do you see any changes in the process display (you may have to wait a few seconds or refresh the process window to see a change)?"

The only change I have noticed is in the number of reds/reductions (it increases when I call the function from iex). However there was no explanation of what "Reds" is or why it increased.

After a quick web surf I could not find anything understandable for a beginner (a lot of elixir/erlang in production articles popup). Could you folks give a nice, simple answer to this.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a BEAM application, you can potentially have millions of processes running at the same time. In order to ensure that each process gets (roughly) equal share of the available CPU(s), the VM counts reductions. One reduction is essentially equivalent to one function call.

Comment: Cheers! I thought it should be something simple